# What's the suggest way to shutdown akka remote client

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

If I disable line A, the HelloRemote app cannot receive the message "hello world", it seems if we shutdown local actor system too quick, the message will not be sent to remote?

Of course, local actor could wait a message from remote to confirm the message already received, but if we add such code, the process will be synchronous, I do not want the thing become something like RPC.

I just want to make it asynchronous, and also do not want to waste the time by "Thread.sleep(3000)", I want the client quit asap, any suggestion?

HelloRemote.scala

```
package remote

import akka.actor._

object HelloRemote extends App  {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloRemoteSystem")
  val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActor], name = "RemoteActor")
}

class RemoteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
        println(s"received message '$msg'")
  }
}
```

Local.scala

```
package local

import akka.actor._

object Local extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("LocalSystem")
  val localActor = system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor], name = "LocalActor")
  localActor ! "START"
}

class LocalActor extends Actor {
  val remote = context.actorSelection(
     "akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor")

  def receive = {
    case "START" =>
        remote ! "hello world"
        Thread.sleep(3000) // Line A
        context.stop(self)
        context.system.shutdown
  }
}
```

Also, paste application.conf for your easy try.

remote part:

```
    akka {
      actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
      }
      remote {
        netty.tcp {
          hostname = "127.0.0.1"
          port = 5150
        }
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
      }
      log-dead-letters = off
      log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
    }
```

local part:

```
    akka {
      actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
      }
      remote {
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
      }
      log-dead-letters = off
      log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `context.stop(self)`, you could send a message `PoisonPill` to self, remove Line A  and upon receiving `PoisonPill` message you could shutdown system

Comment: @curious, I wonder how can I do my action after self ! PoisonPill, it seems, akka will handle this message by itself, so something like next not work.  case PoisonPill => println("wow")

Comment: Correct, Make `case object` for custom message like `KillLocal` and send it to `self` and upon receiving `KillLocal` do `context.stop(self)`;
        `context.system.shutdown`

Comment: @curious No, this did not work, self ! 'done case 'done =>
        println("wow")
        context.stop(self)
        context.system.shutdown  we will see the remote still did not receive anything

Answer (score 0):

As the simpliest thing, remote actor can send back Poison pill to local client.

Like this:

```
sender ! Kill
```

you can read here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Killing_an_Actor

Or you can choose some "secret" message that tell your local actor to do something before stop itself.

Short example. Remote part:

```
class RemoteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
     case msg: String =>
               println(s"received message '$msg'")
               sender ! "secretWord"
  }     
}
```

Local part:

```
 class LocalActor extends Actor {
  val remote = context.actorSelection(
    "akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor")

  def receive = {
      case "START" =>
            remote ! "hello world"
      case "secretWord" =>
      context.stop()
  }

  def postStop(): Unit = { 
     //do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: OP already mentioned he does not want local actor to wait for a confirmation from remote actor and then act upon it,

Comment: I think he can't do it without getting some message from remote actor. Another thing that i can suggest is "ask", but in this case we need wait a reply from remote actor. If somebody now how to do it, tell us please.

Comment: After sending a message to remote actor you can send a `PoisonPill` to self that will serve the purpose.

Comment: But in this way you are not insured from something wrong that may happened  that remote actor will not get message. As I understand  main purpose was to verify that remote actor got a message and then stop itself.